# Android WebView Save State

Tags: android, webview, android-camera, onresume, savestate

I have an app with a WebView. There is a page with Upload Photo button so I use the openFileChooser. Sometimes I have a problem when the camera is chosen. The activity restarts and the webview is back on the beginning. How I can save the state of the activity? Please give an example (I saw that a good example of this would be useful).

Answer (score 0):

You can save the Webview in Android Cache :
Use WebView Setting :

```html
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

This will help you ..happy codeing