# save android WebView cache

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, webview, save

iam very search but notfind any answer please help for me to save webview cache and load no internet my code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
initWebView(webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);  
webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer from my this Answwer :
[Android WebView Save State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789299/android-webview-save-state)

Or webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

It will save your webView in cache.